# How would one find foreclosures in Canada, Newfoundland?

Tags: canada, real-estate, foreclosure

I am starting to look for a new home, and am wondering how one would find foreclosure in Newfoundland.

Comment: I thought everyone got free housing and free health care in the peoples republic of canada - why would there be a foreclosure?

Comment: As with everything else, we in Canada lag 5 years behind the USA. Our housing market is heading south now. An [mls.ca](http://www.mls.ca) specializing in foreclosures would be a great tool.

Comment: Can you go negative on reputation points to offer that bounty?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer my points are already taken from me...

Answer (score 3):

The best way I've found to find foreclosures is to talk to a local real estate agent.   They should be able to give you a list of bank owned properties. Unfortunately, I haven't found a good online source for foreclosures.

Comment: Interesting, I never suspected that a real estate agent would have that info(I am new to the game) would foreclosures end up on mls listings then? Obviously they would not be advertised as foreclosures if they were

Comment: The real estate agent will have access to all the houses listed for sale.   I recommend pursuing a house already for sale (already through and done with foreclosure).  These are bank owned homes at this point.    I recommend against buying a foreclosure from the court house because there is a lot of risk in what you are buying and a lot of uncertainty in knowing what other liens are on the property .